# How to disable Firefox from opening "tel" links

Tags: firefox, user-interface, hyperlink, links

On a certain website, you have to click a button to show the phone number, and at the same time it opens the "tel:" link, which opens an annoying popup "allow this website to open tel links? / Choose program..."

How to prevent Firefox from reacting on `tel:` links?

Answer (score 2):

In `about:config`,

Search for `network.protocol-handler.external.tel` so you have the option to add the key (choose Boolean and click `[+]`) and set it to `false`.

Comment: doesn't work, I still get the popup

Comment: Just realised that I don't have this setting anymore, and I don't have the popup when clicking on a tel link (last Firefox 108 under Ubuntu 20).